# DinD with Podman in Gitlab CICD

Tags: gitlab-ci, podman, docker-in-docker

For my projects I would like to add some CICD with integration tests.
For these integration tests I'm using Testcontainers (https://testcontainers.com/) from my C# environment to spin up both a database and services such as RabbitMQ.
I can launch my database container as additional service from my gitlab CICD yml file.
But this is not the way testcontainers are created, these are created through docker.

My company admin has used a rootless version of Podman to run the gitlab runner. I would like to use the DinD example as described here: https://java.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/gitlab_ci/
But this will not do, since this will result in the container to state that it does not have access. From what I have been able to find there is no podman:dind kind of container, so when launching podman as cicd service, it does not expose any ports, therefore I cannot interact with the container.

Does anyone know how to get this up and running?

Comment: Have you tried https://gitlab.com/qontainers/pipglr ?